# Как поместить файл *.rdp в файл EXE cо своей иконкой?

Tags: windows, exe, icon

файл .rdp (удаленный рабочий стол windows) имеет стандартную отображаемую иконку

Мне необходимо поменять ему иконку на свою. И главное так, чтобы она не менялась если этот файл кому то преслать и открыть на другом ПК. т.е. иконка должна быть встроена в файл (так я это понимаю)

Я это вижу так:

Файл .rdp нужно поместить в контейнер EXE вместе с файлом кастомной иконки.

1.Только я не знаю как это сделать?
2. Какой код исполняемой программы?
3. Какой софт нужно использовать?
4. Или можно как то по другому это реализовать?

Comment: можно использовать склейку WinRar и исполняемый файл, приделать иконку и все

Comment: А запускать вы будите программу в винде `%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe` с [параметрами](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/mstsc.html)

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение самостоятельно.
Возможно кому то пригодится.

Все просто нужно запаковать в архив через архиватор RAR С расширением EXE

настроить запуск файла .rdp при создании архива

добавить файл .ico тоже при создании архива

Инструкцию нашел на Ютубе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5krjb_sH9s

Там все подробности. спасибо автору!!!

Comment: или 7 zip чтоб не покупать лицензию на rar